Xcode NSMetaDataQuery error on device running IOS 17.5 - [ERROR] couldn't fetch remote operation IDs
Xcode 15.4 running on various IOS simulators and hardware devices from IOS 14.5 to 17.5.
Part of my code presents a backup/restore page to the user which uses NSMetaDataQuery to update the GUI for files being uploaded or downloaded.
On every device I run the code everything works as expected EXCEPT one which is an iPhone 11 running IOS 17.5; there I get the following error once I start the query:
[ERROR] couldn't fetch remote operation IDs: NSError: Cocoa 257 "The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
"Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""
Due to this error I am getting no query updates and thus unable to display whether the file needs to upload, download or is synchronised.
I am not initiating any upload or download of the backup file since it is placed in the ubiquitous container and I leave the up/download of the file over to IOS; all I do with the query is monitor the status of the file and take appropriate action to show the user the percentage of up/downloaded file.
As said before it is only the one device causing me headaches so I don't know whether it has anything to do with IOS 17.5 that Apple have made changes that I am unaware of. I have access to an iPhone and an iPad running some version of IOS 16 and it's performing flawlessly.
running 'startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()' which has been suggested by some returns 'true' on the simulator and 'false' on a device, but even then all devices work except one; so that does not seem to be the solution.
Changing the query predicate has not helped either.
How do I drill down to find the culprit - I'm at my wits' end.
My very simple query initializer and startup:
    func initialiseQuery() {
        query = NSMetadataQuery.init()
        query.operationQueue = .main
        query.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]
        query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, fileUrl.lastPathComponent)

 query.operationQueue?.addOperation({ [weak self] in
            self?.query.start()
            self?.query.enableUpdates()
        })
    }

SOLVED:
So last night I managed to sneak off with my wife's phone, updated it from IOS 16* to IOS 17.5.1 and 'viola', same problem arose, so then I figured it had to be something with the IOS....or not.
I drilled down on the NSPredicate again and after some changes the following now works:
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, fileUrl.relativePath)
--And that now works--
The above mentioned error is still present on the device, but I can for the foreseeable future ignore it.
And the 'startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()' now returns 'true'
